# CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check in heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, cors

I got problem when deploy my reactjs client:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://sephora-api-demo.herokuapp.com/api/admin/admin-product/product-properties' from origin 'https://sephora-admin.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

And this is my cors config:

```
app.use(
cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: [
        'https://sephora-admin.herokuapp.com',
        'https://sephora-client-app.herokuapp.com',
        "http://localhost:3000",
        "http://localhost:3001",
    ],
})
);
```

help~

Comment: Are you entirely sure that you've deployed that code to your server? Do you see anything in your server-side logs?

Comment: im pretty sure that i have deloyed. there is no log in my server